# About crystal of water

Tags: water, crystals

[image: This picture is about crystal dependent on temperature]

These shapes are applied to snow crystal. I know that there is a difference between making snow crystal and just freezing water. Can I observe these kinds of crystal just by freezing water? If I can observe these kind of crystals, just by freezing water, will the same result appear?(about crystal dependent on temperature)

Answer (score 1):

Almost certainly not. These shapes appear when water vapor deposits on a small ice crystal. When water freezes into ice, the physics taking place at the surface is quite different from the physics of a snowflake growing from water vapor.